# Window Scroll not working/Reset on tabChange

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular5, ng-bootstrap

Window Scroll not working/Reset on tabChange
I have created a sample angular 2 app, where i have used ngb-tabset(for creating tab views).

I encountered the problem when i click on button to navigate next the tab window scroll does not reset.
it is still bottom of the page.

I tired `window.scrollTo(0,0)` but did not work

Can someone help me for this issue.
here is my plunkr url
    http://plnkr.co/edit/DYnF85V8V2MGVbCVwwoH?p=preview

I have added button on each tab when i click on button, tab data or controll it should be focus or move top of the tab/page.

Comment: cannot see the code part which should do the scrolling in the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this you have to be bind to @Output "tabChange".

On your component.ts :

```
export class NgbdTabsetSelectbyid {
  public onTabChange($event: Event) {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
  }
}
```

and on your view :

```
<ngb-tabset #t="ngbTabset" (tabChange)="onTabChange($event)">
```

Example base on your plinkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/vTKMKLwL8B6woLqeQvqO?p=preview